# How to turn off Jasmine randomization for a single file?

Tags: testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

Tests are executed in random order by default from Jasmine 3.x (see [pull request](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/pull/927)). I understand that it is bad practice to have inter-tests dependencies. However, I have a legitimate use case for this for a single test file and require tests to run sequentially. Currently, I have done the following in `karma.config.js` file to disable the randomization:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        random: false
      }
    }
  })
}
```

I would still like to have randomization turned on for the rest of the tests. Is there any way I can set `random: false` for that specific file? If not, are there any other alternatives to this?

Comment: There is a way if you do not need to have all tests (random and non-random ones) executed in a single run. Would this help or are you looking for a single run solution?

Comment: I need a single run solution, unfortunately